# Induced $G$-module - question about notation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules, representation-theory, tensor-products

In *Algebra Vol. 2* the author, P. M. Cohn writes the following in chapter 7.7

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of finite index $r$ in $G$ and consider a right $H$-module $U$. From it we can form a right $G$-module
> $$\tag{1}
> \text{ind}^G_H=U^G=U\bigotimes_HkG,
> $$
> called the *induced* $G$-module.

My question now is, what exactly does the $H$ in $\bigotimes_H$ mean? In chapter 4.7 he defines $U\otimes_K V$ as the tensor product of two $K$-modules $U$ and $V$, where $K$ is a commutative ring, but I do not see how I 'translate' this notation to that in equation $(1)$ where $U$ is an $H$-module and $kG$ a $G$-module with $H$ and $G$ being groups.

**Edit**: I have an additional doubt. He goes on to write

> To find the representation afforded by $U^G$ we note that the subspace $U\otimes H=\{u\otimes 1|u\in U\}$ of $U^G$ is an $H$-module in a natural way: for any $h\in H$ we have $(u\otimes 1)h=uh\otimes 1$. More generally we can define the subspace $U\otimes Ha=\{u\otimes a|u\in U\}$ of $(1)$ as an $H^a$, where $H^a=a^{-1}Ha$, by the rule
> $$
> (u\otimes a)x=uaxa^{-1}\otimes a,\quad \text{for } x\in H^a.
> $$

Here I do not understand why he writes $U\otimes H$, which appears to denote the tensor product between an $H$-module, $U$, and a group $H$?

Comment: $H$ here means $kH$. Note that $kG$ is a $(kH,kG)$-bimodule, so one can form the tensor product of a right $kH$-module and a $(kH,kG)$-bimodule to form a right $kG$-module.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I still don't know what it means. I know that when $U$ is an $H$-module and $kG$ a $G$-module, and both are defined over a common field $K$, then there exists a tensor product of their vector spaces $U\otimes_K kG$, which we can turn into a right- $H\times G$ module by the rule  $U\otimes_K kG(h,g)= Uh\otimes_K kGg$. But in the book, he does not explain what it means when writing $\otimes_H$ (or $\otimes_{kH}$) instead of $\otimes_K$.

Comment: On p161 Cohn discusses tensor products of modules and bimodules over non-commutative rings, such as $kH$. It's in the section called "The tensor product of modules".

Comment: @DavidA.Craven, thank you. I read the first part of that section about the tensor products over commutative rings and will try and go through the part with non-commutative rings to see if I can understand the above. Can you please look at my edit and see if you can answer that part too?